# Jquery get specific *instance of the class* that triggered an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, events

I am working on a game in which JSON data is turned into a bunch of classes that are painted on top of the main map.  Each icon is a small 20x20 pixel box.  Moving the cursor over each box is then meant to change another div's html to relay the information "hidden" inside of each class's value.

My code goes like this:

```
$('.City_Palace').mousemove(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var x = Math.floor((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft +  $("#scrollWindow").scrollLeft()) / tileSize);
            var y = Math.floor((e.pageY - this.offsetTop + $("#scrollWindow").scrollTop())/tileSize);
            var text = $('#WorldMapMessage').html();
            alert(e.target.className); 
            $('#WorldMapMessage').html(x +', '+ y + " " + $(this).val());

           // alert($(this).val());
        });
```

This code currently brings up an alert box with the classname of what caused the event.  However, what I need to know is which precise instance of the .City_Palace class triggered the event so I can display the appropriate text.  If I were using ids instead of classes, this would be trivial, but for this I need to use classes and know which one is invoking the event.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already seem to be doing this.

Inside the function you pass into `.mousemove()`, you have access to `this`, which refers to the specific instance of the element that's being hovered on. You can use it to get anything else you might need from that specific instance of the element. For example:

```
$('.City_Palace').mousemove(function(e) {

  // $(this) is the specific instance of .City_Palace that's being hovered on.
  alert($(this).attr("class")); // Alert the class name.

});
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, however, on the last line of the method where $(this).val() is being called.  HTML source confirms that the value for the instance of the class is not empty, but what gets returned is an empty string.

Comment: @user1433070: `.val()` never got the HTML source of anything.

Comment: `.val()` is only used for form elements, like a text input box, which is why it doesn't return anything. What are you looking to get from that instance of `$('.City_Palace')`? What do you mean by "value for the instance of the class"?

Comment: You are right, I was using .val() improperly.  I've switched over to using accessing the class's html instead, but it's a bit ugly as the text itself appears on the map.  Nothing I can't work around, though.  Thanks!